# Custom Django Form Not Saving

Tags: python, django, forms, save, updating

I am trying to use customize the output of my form by [this method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template). For example:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.message.errors }}
    <label for="id_message">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.message }}
</div>
```

If I render the form as `form.as_p`, everything works fine, but rendering the fields individually does not work.

I have some fields that I want to be hidden so am trying to render each individually. The fields I am trying to hide are given `null=True, blank=True` attributes in the model class, and are therefore not required.

No errors are being shown, rather the page is refreshed and the data is not updated. I'm not sure what I could be missing given these factors. Here is the view:

The view is from [userena](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/views.py):

```
@secure_required
@permission_required_or_403('change_profile', (get_profile_model(), 'user__username', 'username'))
def profile_edit(request, username, edit_profile_form=EditProfileForm,
                 template_name='userena/profile_form.html', success_url=None,
                 extra_context=None, **kwargs):
"""
Edit profile.

Edits a profile selected by the supplied username. First checks
permissions if the user is allowed to edit this profile, if denied will
show a 404. When the profile is successfully edited will redirect to
``success_url``.

:param username:
Username of the user which profile should be edited.

:param edit_profile_form:

Form that is used to edit the profile. The :func:`EditProfileForm.save`
method of this form will be called when the form
:func:`EditProfileForm.is_valid`. Defaults to :class:`EditProfileForm`
from userena.

:param template_name:
String of the template that is used to render this view. Defaults to
``userena/edit_profile_form.html``.

:param success_url:
Named URL which will be passed on to a django ``reverse`` function after
the form is successfully saved. Defaults to the ``userena_detail`` url.

:param extra_context:
Dictionary containing variables that are passed on to the
``template_name`` template. ``form`` key will always be the form used
to edit the profile, and the ``profile`` key is always the edited
profile.

**Context**

``form``
Form that is used to alter the profile.

``profile``
Instance of the ``Profile`` that is edited.
"""
    user = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(),
                             username__iexact=username)

    profile = user.get_profile()

    user_initial = {'first_name': user.first_name,
                    'last_name': user.last_name}

    form = edit_profile_form(instance=profile, initial=user_initial)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = edit_profile_form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile,
                                 initial=user_initial)

        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save()

            if userena_settings.USERENA_USE_MESSAGES:
                messages.success(request, _('Your profile has been updated.'),
                                 fail_silently=True)

            if success_url:
                # Send a signal that the profile has changed
                userena_signals.profile_change.send(sender=None,
                                                    user=user)
                redirect_to = success_url
            else: redirect_to = reverse('userena_profile_detail', kwargs={'username': username})
            return redirect(redirect_to)

    if not extra_context: extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['form'] = form
    extra_context['profile'] = profile
    return ExtraContextTemplateView.as_view(template_name=template_name,
                                            extra_context=extra_context)(request)
```

I am including the html to render the forms using `{% include 'my-template.html' %}`. What could be preventing me from updating the profile object? Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: What do your server logs say when you click submit on the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
{{ form.errors }}
```

somewhere to your template to see if there are any non-field errors !

Comment: I had that exactly the same problem more than once before :)